# redux logger not logging to console

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

There are no actions logged in the console. Any ideas?

store:

```
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

import logger from "redux-logger";
import rootReducer from "../reducers";

const initialState = {
    fetchVideos: []
};

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    applyMiddleware(thunk, logger)
);

export default store;
```

Package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "0.57.1",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.9",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6"
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the logger as a dependency:

`npm i --save redux-logger`

I hope it help you.